# How to combine planning entitiy's ConstraintStreams with related problem fact properties?

Tags: optaplanner

I started to implemented a school timetable scheduling application using OptaPlanner.

Similar to the lesson scheduling example in the documentation, I'd like to optimize a school schedule including constraints such as "A teacher, who works/has less than N hours (per week) should ideally have one (or two, depending on N) days off".

To phrase it differently: Lessons of teachers should not be distributed across the entire week, but their quantity should rather be maximized per day.

Lesson is my only planning entity, the teacher is a problem fact (I guess). Maybe I need to model it in a different way to access the overall distribution of a teacher's timeslots (more specifically: of all the lesson's timeslots belonging to a teacher).

How can I combine the usual constraints, i.e., a teacher can't do two different lessons at the same time etc., defined using the ConstraintFactory creating ConstraintStreams (for Lessons) with a more global property such as the "lesson compactness" for teachers (full days better than distributed over the entire week) who work part time? I can't imagine how to calculate that score by just having access to a constraint stream of lessons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal way to use global information in a constraint is to create a singleton problem fact that stores global information, and use that in your constraint.
For your example, create a `ScheduleGlobalProperties` with a `partTimeTeacherSet` field:

```java
public class ScheduleGlobalProperties {
    Set<String> partTimeTeacherSet;
    // other global properties, constructors, getters...
}
```

Add it as a `@ProblemFactProperty` to your `@PlanningSolution` class:

```java
@PlanningSolution
public class Schedule {
    @ProblemFactProperty
    ScheduleGlobalProperties scheduleGlobalProperties;
    // Other fields, constructors, methods...
}
```

Then in your constraint, you join on the global properties problem fact to access the global properties:

```java
Constraint lessonCompactness(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
    return constraintFactory.forEach(Lesson.class)
        .groupBy(Lesson::getTeacher,
                 ConstraintCollectors.countDistinct(
                     lesson -> lesson.getTimeslot().getDay()
                 ))
        .join(ScheduleGlobalProperties.class)
        .filter((teacher, dayCount, globalProperties) -> globalProperties.getPartTimeTeacherSet().contains(teacher))
        .penalize(HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT, (teacher, dayCount, globalProperties) -> dayCount)
        .asConstraint("Lesson Compactness");
}
```

I don't see how the constraint you specified needed global information though.
An example that uses global information is nurse rostering; `NurseRosterParametrization` is the singleton global properties class (with first and last shift date fields).
In the nurse rostering example, the global properties are used in the `consecutiveFreeDays` constraint to determine how many free days an employee have before their first shift and after their last shift.
See [the nurse rostering source code](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/tree/main/optaplanner-examples/src/main/java/org/optaplanner/examples/nurserostering) for the full example.

Comment: 1/2 Thank you very much for this detailed example and the hint regarding the ProblemFactProperty decorator. I should have looked at the documentation more thoroughly. I already thought I was almost there by implementing the required metric on the Lesson (planning entity having references to problem facts such as teachers). It worked in my unit test but it didn't work while optimizing. The result of this metric was always the same - probably due to the caching mechanism on planning entities?

Comment: 2/2 Regarding the need for global information: Probably you are right, I just need information beyond the current lesson. I need some fixed properties of the lesson's teacher and his/her current (!) lessons on that day. And this is some dynamic attribute of the problem fact which I missed to model correctly. Should I rather use a problem change event? Or is this something that should end up in some global information that may change while optimizing (and therefore must not be cached)?

Comment: One more thing: I think I don't fully understand the groupBy part of your example. Does it count the distinct days for each teacher on which this teacher has (any) lessons? And the contraint then tries to minimize this count for part time teachers? I think I'll try that, that looks awesome. And yes, then I don't need global information, I could use teacher properties for weighting the penalty, I guess.

Comment: I just implemented it using the constraint collector's distinct counting approach - it works perfectly, without global information!