# Use global facts in timefold / optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner, timefold

I am profiling a course-curriculum-like timefold project, where each `Lesson` has a `Timeslot` as planning variable. I manage to improve score calculation significantly by using state in a global singleton. This global state is recalculated on every `Timeslot` change and respected in the score calculation via the following constraint:

```
factory.forEach(Lesson.class).groupBy(t->0,ConstraintCollectors.toList()).impact(
HardMediumSoft.ofHard(1),(key,list)->GlobalState.getSingleton().getImpact()).asConstraint(id);
```

The grouping ensures that the impact of the global state is updated on every change of a `Lesson` and counted for all lessons together only once. Now this constraint definition leads to some wasteful operations like the empty `groupKey t->0` and the somewhat unnecessary `toList()` operation but those unnecessary operations seem to be responsible for my hot path which is the following method call

```
Group1Mapping0CollectorUniNode.createGroupKey
```

Is there a less wasteful definition of such a constraint, so that I can further optimize my hot path?

Note: Using a constraint like

```
factory.forEach(GlobalState.class).impact(t->t.getImpact())
```

as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75923770) did not work as the constraint needs to be recalculated on every change of a `Lesson`-object.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure this global state isn't causing score corruptions? Have you run your code with ~10 minutes of FULL_ASSERT environment mode?

Comment: I am 99 % certain that this approach will break something; at the very least multi-threaded solving, but also likely just any situation where two solvers run at the same time, which could be score analysis, recommendation fit etc.

Comment: @Lukas It definitely causes score corruptions even in FAST_ASSERT but the integration tests I run were fine, so I think it only breaks in situations that are not relevant. My scenario is single threaded. But it speeds up score calculation speed seven times!

Comment: In my experience, there is no such thing as a harmless score corruption. I suggest you scrap this approach, and ask another question where we can discuss your slow constraint instead.

Answer (score 1):

A typical approach for this is to do a join with a singleton:

```
.forEach(MyEntity.class)
.join(MyConstraintConfiguration.class)
.filter((entity, constraintConfig) -> entity.foo > constraintConfig.pauze)
.penalize(..., (entity, constraintConfig) -> entity.foo - constraintConfig.pauze)
```

That singleton is typically a @ProblemFactProperty or a @ContraintConfigurationProperty on the @PlanningSolution class.

Like Lukas said, the Global approach is bugged. A ThreadLocal approach is error-prone. The approach above is fine.

---

There was design debate if we can somehow make that nicer. IIRC Lukas and me considered something (at least structure wise) like `.expandWithSingletonProblemFact(Class)`. But that would be the exact same structure as `.join(Class)`, although it would be clearer to read and might enable performance gains. Something to discuss on Timefold's Github Discussions.

Comment: I didn't manage to get both '@ProblemFactProperty' and '@ConstraintConfigurationProvider' to work (I did not find '@ConstraintConfigurationProperty'). But I started a Github Discussion.

Comment: I've seen it successfully used a few times, must be something in the way it's annotated.